# CacheManager - Dependency injection

Tags: c#, cache, dependency-injection

I create a cache manager to manage a system of cache exchangeable by another implementation.

I use the `CacheManager` class throughout my program. If I want to change the implementation I simply add a provider and I add it in my dependency container

Is it correct to do this like that?

**ICache**

```
namespace Caching
{
    public interface ICache
    {
        object Get(string key);

        void Set(string key, object value);
    }
}
```

**ICacheManager**

```
namespace Caching
{
    public static class CacheManager
    {
        private static ICache cache;
        private static readonly object syncRoot = new object();

        private static ICache Cache
        {
            get
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (cache == null)
                    {
                        cache = Container.Instance.Resolve<ICache>();
                    }
                }

                return cache;
            }
        }

        public static object Get(string key)
        {
            return Cache.Get(key);
        }

        public static void Set(string key, object value)
        {
            Cache.Set(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

**MemoryCacheProvider**

```
using System.Runtime.Caching;

namespace Caching.Providers
{
    public class MemoryCacheProvider : ICache
    {
        public object Get(string key)
        {
            return MemoryCache.Default.Get(key);
        }

        public void Set(string key, object value)
        {
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(key, value, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));
        }
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Container.Instance.RegisterType<ICache, MemoryCacheProvider>();
}
```

Comment: You have asked thrice for this question to be deleted. [Stack Exchange policy forbids deletion of posts that have upvoted answers.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) Furthermore, [self-vandalism is against the rules.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209436/148099) I have rolled back and locked this post.

Answer (score 4):

You are not doing dependency injection but using another pattern which is called [service locator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx) which isn't by the way so cool becasue classes using it depend on the `Container`:

> ```
> cache = Container.Instance.Resolve<ICache>();
> ```

The `CacheManager` resolves an `ICache` from the `Container`. None of your classes should even know that the `Container` exists (but the one that configures it).

You should remove the `CacheManager` entirely and instead correctly inject the `ICache` to classes that require it.

```
class ThisClassRequiresCache
{
    public ThisClassRequiresCache(ICache cache) { .. }
}
```

Your dependency injection framework should handle the injection.

---

As far as the private `Cache` properety is concerned you should add another `cache == null` check to prevent unnecessary locks after the cache has already been created:

```
get
{
    if (cache == null)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            if (cache == null)
            {
                cache = Container.Instance.Resolve<ICache>();
            }
        }
    }

    return cache;
}
```